# Retrieve specific information from json string request

Tags: php, android, database

In my android application there is two spinners and the second spinner is dependant on the first one and the first spinner shows the list of cities and the second spinner shows the colleges available in that perticular city so there is one json for the cities and it is used by the first spinner and another json which returns value of colleges and now I want to use same json for all the choices made in first spinner so when user changes city from the first spinner the json should return only colleges available in that perticular city and second spinner should be filled by it .so pls tell me what I need to modify in my json or php file thanks

Comment: Please provide us with a sample of the JSON you are working with.

Comment: The json for the first spinner is:[this](http://thehostels.in/spinner_city_json.php) and json for the second spinner is :[this](http://thehostels.in/spinner_states_json%20(5).php)

Comment: Please someone help me@michaelcarrano

Comment: What I need to do basically please tell me I have to submit my project very soon

Comment: Could someone reply any answer or suggest something pls